# How is Firestore's pricing for array, maps and subcollections?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

As I was studying Firestore's pricing and looking for ways to minimize costs in my application, I couldn't find an answer to this question:

Does reading from subcollections, arrays and maps count as 1 read per item or can I read the whole array for a single read?

I know a better model can do the trick, but I'd like to have this clarified before that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The billing applies to each document read, no matter where it lives, no matter how it was queried.  It doesn't matter what the document contains.  For mobile and web clients, the read will always return the entire contents of the document.  There is no separate billing for the individual fields inside a document.

Comment: So that means using an array instead of a subcollection could be cheaper? I've seen some info that subcollections's documents counts as a document too and cause the reading count to increase.

Comment: Organizing a document under a subcollection doesn't have any affect on billing.  That's what the first sentence in the answer is saying - a document read is always going to be billed no matter where it lives.  If you want to use an array instead, that could work.  You just need to be aware that documents have a max size, and you can't store large numbers of array elements.

Comment: Is there a depth limit/constraint within a doc? In the [docs about data types](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#data_types), both Android​ examples have Maps of primitive values, but the Web & Swift docs have subtly different examples where one Map value is itself an object.

Comment: I ask because that might be another factor when deciding Array/Map vs sub-collection.

Comment: @AjahnCharles Please post a separate question to explain more clearly the problem you're running into.

Comment: I don't currently have a specific issue. I was just trying to understand the OPs array approach in more detail (and pass on that the docs are different for different languages - I can't see a proper channel for reporting that). Edit: nvm, I'll use "send feedback"

Answer (score 0):

Subcollections have a parent document. By calling it you make one call, one billed operation, by then calling a subdocument in a subcollection, you make another call, another billed op.

Using subcollections can double your cost, each added subdocument query divide that doubling.